# Split sublist while maintaining original lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a large list called `coordinates`, where each entry looks like this below. Calling `print coordinates[1]`:

```
["0 0 255 \\n'", " '229 125 5 \\n'", " '229 126 6 \\n'", " '229 127 7 \\n'", " '229 128 8 \\n'", " '229 129 7 \\n'", " '229 130 8 \\n'", " '229 131 9 \\n'", " '229 132 9 \\n'", " '229 133 12 \\n'", " '229 134 9 \\n'", " '229 137 5 \\n'", " '629 140 5 \\n'", " '631 140 5 \\n'", " '632 140 5 \\n'", " '633 140 8 \\n'", " '422 141 5 \\n'", " '628 141 9 \\n'", " '629 141 11 \\n'", " '630 141 12 \\n'", " '631 141 12 \\n'", " '632 141 12 \\n'", " '633 141 11 \\n'", " '634 141 5 \\n'", " '422 142 9 \\n'", " '628 142 9 \\n'", " '629 142 12 \\n'", " '630 142 13 \\n'", " '631 142 11 \\n'", " '632 142 12 \\n'", " '633 142 11 \\n'", " '422 143 9 \\n'", " '628 143 8 \\n'", " '629 143 10 \\n'", " '630 143 11 \\n'", " '631 143 12 \\n'", " '632 143 11 \\n'", " '633 143 9 \\n'", " '422 144 5 \\n'", " '628 144 8 \\n'", " '629 144 12 \\n'", " '630 144 12 \\n'", " '631 144 10 \\n'", " '632 144 9 \\n'", " '633 144 6 \\n'", " '629 145 8 \\n'", " '630 145 8 \\n'", " '631 145 8 \\n'", " '632 145 8 \\n'", " '632 146 5 \\n'", " '"]
```

So each entry is a sublist. I can then call `coordinates[1][1]` for example, to get `'229 125 5 \n'`.

I'd now like to create another sublist that breaks each `coordinate[i][j]` into new sublists consisting of each number shown. I'd like `coordinates[1][1]` to return `['299', '125', '5']` so then I can call something in the form of `coordinates[i][j][k]` to get just one number. But I'd like to keep this all as part of my larger lists too. How can I do this?

Here's what I've tried, which didn't change anything about `coordinates` (it didn't create my desired additional sublists):

```
for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    for j in range(len(coordinates[i])):
        coordinates[i][j].split(' ')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = ["0 0 255 \\n'", " '229 125 5 \\n'", " '229 126 6 \\n'", " '229 127 7 \\n'", " '229 128 8 \\n'", " '229 129 7 \\n'", " '229 130 8 \\n'", " '229 131 9 \\n'", " '229 132 9 \\n'", " '229 133 12 \\n'", " '229 134 9 \\n'", " '229 137 5 \\n'", " '629 140 5 \\n'", " '631 140 5 \\n'", " '632 140 5 \\n'", " '633 140 8 \\n'", " '422 141 5 \\n'", " '628 141 9 \\n'", " '629 141 11 \\n'", " '630 141 12 \\n'", " '631 141 12 \\n'", " '632 141 12 \\n'", " '633 141 11 \\n'", " '634 141 5 \\n'", " '422 142 9 \\n'", " '628 142 9 \\n'", " '629 142 12 \\n'", " '630 142 13 \\n'", " '631 142 11 \\n'", " '632 142 12 \\n'", " '633 142 11 \\n'", " '422 143 9 \\n'", " '628 143 8 \\n'", " '629 143 10 \\n'", " '630 143 11 \\n'", " '631 143 12 \\n'", " '632 143 11 \\n'", " '633 143 9 \\n'", " '422 144 5 \\n'", " '628 144 8 \\n'", " '629 144 12 \\n'", " '630 144 12 \\n'", " '631 144 10 \\n'", " '632 144 9 \\n'", " '633 144 6 \\n'", " '629 145 8 \\n'", " '630 145 8 \\n'", " '631 145 8 \\n'", " '632 145 8 \\n'", " '632 146 5 \\n'", " '"]
new_s = filter(None, map(lambda x:re.findall('\d+', x), s))
```

Output:

```
[['0', '0', '255'], ['229', '125', '5'], ['229', '126', '6'], ['229', '127', '7'], ['229', '128', '8'], ['229', '129', '7'], ['229', '130', '8'], ['229', '131', '9'], ['229', '132', '9'], ['229', '133', '12'], ['229', '134', '9'], ['229', '137', '5'], ['629', '140', '5'], ['631', '140', '5'], ['632', '140', '5'], ['633', '140', '8'], ['422', '141', '5'], ['628', '141', '9'], ['629', '141', '11'], ['630', '141', '12'], ['631', '141', '12'], ['632', '141', '12'], ['633', '141', '11'], ['634', '141', '5'], ['422', '142', '9'], ['628', '142', '9'], ['629', '142', '12'], ['630', '142', '13'], ['631', '142', '11'], ['632', '142', '12'], ['633', '142', '11'], ['422', '143', '9'], ['628', '143', '8'], ['629', '143', '10'], ['630', '143', '11'], ['631', '143', '12'], ['632', '143', '11'], ['633', '143', '9'], ['422', '144', '5'], ['628', '144', '8'], ['629', '144', '12'], ['630', '144', '12'], ['631', '144', '10'], ['632', '144', '9'], ['633', '144', '6'], ['629', '145', '8'], ['630', '145', '8'], ['631', '145', '8'], ['632', '145', '8'], ['632', '146', '5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

So, when you use "split" you are NOT changing the values in place. The method returns a list created based on the argument you used and returns that but it is a new value, in a different space in memory.

In order to use those values in the future, you need to ASSIGN them to something.

Using your code you can try something like this:

```
In [2]: coordinates = [["0 0 255 \\n'", " '229 125 5 \\n'", " '229 126 6 \\n'"], ["999 0 255 \\n'", " '999 125 5 \\n'", " '999 126 6 \\n'"]]

In [3]: for i in range(len(coordinates)):
   ...:     for j in range(len(coordinates[i])):
   ...:         coordinates[i][j] = coordinates[i][j].split(' ')
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [4]: coordinates
Out[4]: 
[[['0', '0', '255', "\\n'"],
  ['', "'229", '125', '5', "\\n'"],
  ['', "'229", '126', '6', "\\n'"]],
 [['999', '0', '255', "\\n'"],
  ['', "'999", '125', '5', "\\n'"],
  ['', "'999", '126', '6', "\\n'"]]]
```

This is still really bad code in the sense that it is hard to read, and does not take advantage of python's great facilities to deal with data (you should avoid the fors and use map whenever possible) but I wanted to write it that way to help you see where your mistake was.

I think the other answers you are getting are better code, and you should learn from them. But this adds as it helps you understand where your stuff was failing.

Also, as the results show, the split(' ') was NOT enough to clean your data. I think the answer with re is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

`coordinates = [x[:-3].split() for x in original_list]`